# SQLite for Ionic returning error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using Firefox and Chrome for development. I installed the sqlite plugin but there's always error when firing openDB command on:

firefox(TypeError: n.sqlitePlugin is undefined ng-cordova.min.js (line 9, col 19046))

and

chrome(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined ng-cordova.min.js:9ng-cordova.min.js:9)

I don't know what did I do wrong. Please help.

Comment: Hi , While in the browser check for the existence of sqlite if not present then default to webSQL , the code could be something like this , (based omn the framework u are using it would change)     if(window.sqlitePlugin !== undefined) {
            console.log('opening sqlite DB ');
            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("ECM_MOBILE");
        } else {
            console.log('opening Web SQL DB ');
            db = window.openDatabase("ECM_MOBILE", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        }

Answer (score 0):

SQlite plugin will be activated while you are running the application in mobile and it will not be available in browsers. Try running your app in mobile and check.

Answer (score 0):

While in the browser check for the existence of sqlite if not present then default to webSQL , the code could be something like this , (based omn the framework u are using it would change)

```
 if(window.sqlitePlugin !== undefined) {
        console.log('opening sqlite DB ');
        db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("MyDB");
    } else {
        console.log('opening Web SQL DB ');
        db = window.openDatabase("MyDB", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    }
```